Did I lose MySQL database after deleting Docker container?
I setup a local WordPress site using Docker on macOS.
I deleted the WordPress container, which had WordPress, MySQL, and phpmyadmin, from the Docker app using Delete --> Delete forever.
Restarting the WordPress container using docker compose up -d, it is showing the WordPress first time installation flow.
Does this mean that the database is deleted?
Is the database deleted after deleting the container?
If not how to recover it?
docker-compose.yml:
services:
# mysql
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: RootPwd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: WPDatabase
      MYSQL_USER: WPUser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: MySQLPwd
  
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: RootPwd
  
  # wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: WPUser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: MySQLPwd
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: WPDatabase
# Similar to MySQL image variables, the last four lines define the main variables needed for the WordPress container to work properly with the MySQL container.
    volumes:
      ["./:/var/www/html"]
volumes:
  mysql: {}


From what I see you run 3 containers, db, phpmyadmin and wordpress. Which one you delete?

@RomeoNinov All of them

Do you see any result from command docker volume ls?

@RomeoNinov yes I do see a lot of volumes from my other projects but not the one for wordpress/mysql.

Then it's gone.

There are no listed volumes for the mysql container, so any files written would have been to an anonymous overlay to the container image it's self.
If the container was just stopped then it would be possible to start the container again or do a docker commit to save a copy of the files.
But if the container has been deleted (e.g. by a docker compose down) then the changes/new files are likely lost.
If you have root access then I suggest you look in /var/lib/docker/volumes there may be residual directories under there which may have the files you are looking for under the sub directory _data
